# Number of automorphisms of graphs of bounded valences

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory

Given a finite graph G of valence 3. Is there a (good) upper bound (maybe a constant depending on the number of edges) on the number of automorphisms of G?

I try to find on google if someone did it before, but I cannot find anything.

Comment: I guess you mean finite graph. Upper bound? lower bound? depending on other parameters? could you be more specific?

Comment: Do you mean every vertex of $G$ is of degree 3?

Answer (score 3):

I would guess the worst case is n/4 copies of $K_4$. Here you get $(n/4)!24^{n/4}$ automorphisms.

Comment: One can also take the complete graph $K_n$ and replace every vertex by an $n$-gon so that the degree of every vertex becomes $3$. . The number of vertices becomes $\sim n^2$ and the number of automorphisms $\gt n!$.

Answer (score 1):

If disconnected cubic graphs are allowed, then probably user36212's answer is best possible for $n$ a multiple of 4. Is there a simple proof?

If only connected cubic graphs are considered, [Opstall and Verliche](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0608645) found the best possible bound. It is somewhat messy so I won't state it here.

[Here on mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/136929/maximum-automorphism-group-for-a-3-connected-cubic-graph) I asked the same question for 3-connected cubic graphs. It remains unsolved.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are working with a 3-regular graph $G$, here is an elementary upper bound for the number of automorphisms $f:G\rightarrow G$. Denote the number of vertices of $G$ by $n$. Starting from a vertex $v$, there are at most $n$ choices for $f(v)$. The three vertices connected to $v$ should be mapped to the tree vertices connected to $f(v)$ which is possible in $3!$ ways. Next, pick one of the $n-4$ vertices left, say $w$. There are at most $n-4$ choices for $f(w)$ and $3!$ ways to determine the image under $f$ of vertices connected to $w$. Proceeding like this, we obtain the upper bound 
$6^{\lceil\frac{n}{4}\rceil}\prod_{0\leq4i<n}(n-4i)$ for $\big|{\rm{Aut}}(G)\big|$.

Comment: Which is sharp for n divisible by 4, as shown by n/4 copies of K_4. Nice!